# FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() without using Default FirebaseApp

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I´m trying to use FCM to send Firebase Notifications, but I have a Application using one Firebase Project and a library using another Firebase Project. I want to receive the token from library Firebase Project to receive Firebase Notifications.

When I try directly receive the token using:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

I received a valid token, but from Application Firebase Project. If i try to force in `getInstance()` the library Firebase Project, using:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance("ABC")).getToken();
```

I receive `null`. If I try to use Application or Library Firebase Project passing parameters in `getToken()` as:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(getApplication().getResources().getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), FirebaseMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
```

or

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance("ABC")).getToken(getApplication().getResources().getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), FirebaseMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
```

I received the same valid token from Application Firebase Project.

> the **R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId** is from library project resources

There is another way to receive Library Firebase Project token or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I have had a same problem.
If you start again, you have a valid token ?

Comment: @Initerworker, unfortunately no. I always receive the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()`, because I forgot to set:

```
.setGcmSenderId(getApplication().getResources().getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId))
```

in `FirebaseOptions.Builder()`.
After that change, I receive a valid Library Firebase Token in `getToken()` and in `onTokenRefresh()`

Answer (score 2):

This is my understanding of what you are observing based on my experiments and the documentation.

When you first call `getToken()` using a `FirebaseApp` other then the default, there is no token and communication with the server is required to produce one.  A null value is returned and the process to fetch a token is initiated. The [documentation for getToken()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getToken()) says it returns *"the master token or null if the token is not yet available"*.  After a few seconds the token is received. You can detect that event using the `onTokenRefresh()` method of [FirebaseInstanceIdService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService), if you have implemented that.  On subsequent calls to `getToken()` for the non-default app, the token will be present and returned immediately by `getToken()`.

I think the calls to get a scoped token always return a token because they are blocking ([see docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getInstance(com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp))), and wait for the interaction with the server to complete before returning a result.

Comment: after the change that I explained below, I receive a valid token in getToken() and in onTokenRefresh() too. Thanks for the help.